# Having an issue with a scroll view moving in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uiscrollview

I am having an issue with a scrollview when switching `UIViewControllers`. When I navigate between `UIViewControllers` the `Scrollview` seems to adjust itself. How do I stop the `scrollview` from moving?

Comment: Your question is not clear. A scroll view does not have view controllers. A view controller controls views, not the other way round.

Comment: When I switch views my scrollview jumps up like it's adjusting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the scrollEnabled property to turn off scrolling when you want to switch controllers.  [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];

Comment: I'm having an issue with my scrollview jumping up when I switch views. It works fine when scrolling. It seems the scroll view has to reset it's self when switching views

Comment: If you turn off scrolling before you switch views, then turn it back on, does it work correctly?  If not, then you probably have some other code that is resetting the scroll view.